# How to using get method without field name?

Tags: php, get, field

for example the link is:
http://www.test.com/abc.php?config.scp

Is it possible to get the value "config.scp" in the php program? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use example links that look like real ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data is contained in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple string, use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

If you still need an array with rest of the variables, use `$_GET`. If you `var_dump( $_GET )` on link you provided, you should get:

```
array(1) {
  ["config_scp"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You can easily parse it now.

There's one gotcha with dot in that particular query string tho. PHP variables cannot contain dots, so it's changed into `_`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**... in that case data is field name but be aware that dot is not allowed in $_GET array index.

Also, you can explode `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` with `&` character and look into resulting array for element's value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hy

See this example:

`$url = 'http://www.test.com/abc.php?config.scp';`

`$p_url = end(explode('?', $url));`

`echo $p_url;`

Comment: this is exactly what $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] returns!